# ¿Cómo acceder a las variables de una clase utilizando una función amiga de otra clase?

Tags: c++, funciones, herencia

Quiero que la función "suma" de la clase B pueda acceder y modificar los valores de las variables "a, b" de la clase A, utilizando métodos/funciones amigas

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  

class A; // Declaración previa de la clase A  

class B {  
    private:  
        int c;  
   public:  
        void suma(A numero);  
};  

class A {  
   private:  
        friend void B::suma(A numero); // Hacer amigo al método/función "suma" de la clase B  
        int a, b;  
   public:  
        A();  
};  

void B::suma(A numero) {  
   numero.a = 1;        // <-- No puedo acceder a estas variables  
   numero.b = 4;        // <-- No puedo acceder a estas variables  

   c = numero.a + numero.b; // <-- Esto es lo que quiero hacer  

   cout << c << endl;  
}  

main() {  
    B objeto;  
    objeto.suma();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es el siguiente:

```
class B {  
    private:  
        int c;  
   public:  
        void suma(A numero);  
};

main() {  
    B objeto;  
    objeto.suma(); // <<--- AQUI!!!
}
```

Fíjate en que la firma de la función espera que a `suma` le pases un objeto de tipo `A` mientras que tu no le estás pasando nada.

Cambia la llamada a, por ejemplo:

```
objeto.suma(A());
```

... o añade un valor por defecto en la firma de la función:

```
class B {  
    private:  
        int c;  
   public:  
        void suma(A numero = A());  
};
```

y verás como el error desaparece. El programa seguirá sin compilar porque te falta implementar el constructor por defecto de `A` (salvo que esa implementación la hayas omitido en el ejemplo que has puesto en tu pregunta).

Un saludo